# How to use single-thread script to do batch processing?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, batch

I have a single-thread python script that gets used like this:

> python -c "arg"

I also have a *.txt file with many `arg`, each in one single line in the respective *.txt. A text file, say `1.txt` looks as follows:

```
arg1
arg2
arg3
arg4
```

Now I want to run the python script with all this arguments, one by one as the script does not allow more than one argument.

How can I process this arguments in batch mode using commandline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
for i in *.txt
do
   while read line
   do
     python -c "$line"
   done < $i
done
```

Comment: Not working. The python script takes the text file as argument, not its content.

Comment: @mmb : updated the solution

Comment: Totally does the job now!

Answer (score 1):

A very easy solution,

```
cat 1.txt | xargs -I{} python -c "{}"
```

Explanation: `cat` prints all lines and `xargs` makes sure each line is used as argument.

Edit: the `-I{}` means that `{}` should by replaced by the argument.

Comment: Wow, that is indeed easy. But does it take into consideration, that the arguments have to be enclosed by `""`?

Comment: Now it does, see my edit ;) If you have multiple files, simply replace `1.txt` by `*.txt` and it should work as well.